# Automator script to move files to sub-folders using relative paths

Tags: osx-lion, mkdir, automator, mv

I'm new to coding and am using Mac OSX Lion. 
I'm currently trying to create some shell script to run as part of a 'Folder Action' in Automator.
Its job would be to take the files that are dropped into that folder and move them into a sub-folder.

```
MYDIR="${HOME}/Desktop/Documents/Images" 
mkdir "${MYDIR}" 
mv "$@" "${MYDIR}"
```

The script I am using works well, but I want it to function without specifying the absolute path ("${HOME}/Desktop/Documents/Images") in the code, and instead specifying the relative path of the current folder.
This will allow me to use the same 'Folder Action' functionality on other folders.

Any help would be most appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
MYDIR="./Documents/Images"
mkdir "${MYDIR}" 
mv "$@" "${MYDIR}"
```

A single dot . means the current directory.

I believe that in your call to mkdir, you would want to only do it if the directory didn't already exist.

-- Kaydell
http://learnbymac.com

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response...Tried using this code but the new folder is still being created further down in the directory (in USER>JOHNDOE>NEW FOLDER). Rather than in a sub-directory of the folder I am dropping the files into (which is located on the desktop). As I mentioned, I'm aiming for the files to be moved into a sub directory without specifying a path if possible. Much appreciated.

Comment: Try this:  MYDIR="Documents/Images" This is a relative path name.

Answer (score 0):

Add this AppleScript to "~/Library/Scripts/Folder Action Scripts". If the "Folder Action Scripts" folder does not exist, make one.

```
on adding folder items to theFolder after receiving theFiles
    -- Create Subfolders
    do shell script "mkdir -p " & (quoted form of (POSIX path of theFolder)) & "{\"Subfolder 1\",\"Subfolder 2\"}"

    -- Examples of how to move files
    tell application "Finder"
        duplicate theFiles to folder ((theFolder as text) & "Subfolder 1")
        move theFiles to folder ((theFolder as text) & "Subfolder 2")
    end tell
end adding folder items to
```